# What is the status of Marvel Comics as a company in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ms-marvel-2022

In *Ms. Marvel* Season 1 Episode 1 "Generation Why", while Kamala and Bruno were in AvengerCon, it is shown that some of the merchandise there has the logo of the real-life Marvel Comics.

In the screencap below, notice the logo above the "Ant-Man" text in the merchandise:

[image: screencap of Marvel Comics logo as shown in Ms. Marvel Season 1 Episode 1 "Generation Why"]

And compare the logo above to the actual Marvel Comics logo:
[image: Marvel Comics logo]

The logo on the merchandise implies that a company with the same name and logo as the real-life Marvel Comics exists in the MCU and has been licensed to use Avengers / superhero intellectual property for merchandising.

This is the first time I've seen Marvel Comics shown as or implied to be an actual company in the MCU. In-universe or out-of-universe, has it been explained **what exactly is the status of Marvel Comics as a company in the MCU?** What do they do? Are they also a comic book company, or are they limited to selling superhero merchandise? Did they organize the AvengerCon? Are they also owned by the MCU's Disney equivalent?

Comment: Marvel Comics Group has existed in the mainstream *comic* continuity since the 1960s. Steve Rogers worked for them for a while, drawing Captain America; https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/captain-america-311-1.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=750&dpr=1.5

Comment: Unfortunately you seem to be specifically asking about Earth-199999, (aka Earth-616 "in universe"). Otherwise the answer would be quite different, as Earth-1218 is the designation (in the comics) for our reality, in which there actually *is* a Marvel Comics which is (presumably) the exact same company you are actually familiar with.  I say presumably because all the multiverse stuff is a bit uh...  spacey-wacey...

Answer (score 11):

**MAYBE**

In one of the *Captain Carter* episodes we see Howard Stark producing a movie on Kid Colt based on the comic book of the same name and the rest of the episode is about whether a movie should be made based off of a comic book. Now Kid Colt is a comic book in the real world and also exists in the MCU as a comic book.

Further also in the movie *Captain America: The First Avenger* there's a lot of merchandise on him including 'comic books', t-shirts and balloons etc. but what's not sure in all of these movies and shows whether these are actually made by Marvel.

As mentioned earlier it's pretty obvious something called Marvel sells merchandise and stuff as seen in *Agents of Shield* and recently *Ms. Marvel* and *Captain America*, but when asked about whether Marvel comics exist in the MCU the directors of many Marvel movies (like *Avengers: Infinity War*, *Endgame* etc....) [the Russo Brothers had to say otherwise](https://movieweb.com/marvel-movies-comics/):

> We took the question to Joe Russo and Anthony Russo, directors of Captain America: The Winter Soldier. Do Marvel Comics exist within the Marvel Cinematic Universe?
>
> "No...I don't think Marvel Comics exist in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.That is a very Community-esque question. Very meta."

There's also [a subreddit related to this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbookmovies/comments/2noue8/do_marvel_comics_exist_within_the_marvel/) that you might find interesting.

Comment: In Marvel comics there is (in-universe) a Marvel Comics company which produces comic books about the various superheroes.

Answer (score 0):

Conjecture, but I'll bet that Marvel in the MCU has the same deal with the heroes as they do in the comics - they license the rights to do comics about the heroes.

IIRC, in DC Comics, proxies have been set up for heroes with secret identities to benefit from licensing without having to reveal their identities.  I'd bet the same is true in the Marvel universe as well.

And somehow Spider-Man has still never found a way to rub two nickels together...